# Spring boot does not compatible with Eureka server

Tags: spring-boot, cloud, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have build an application that is a Eureka server, service registry. 
The pom.xml is as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Microservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>Micro1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- This is a web application -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Tomcat embedded container-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

and the main class that is run the application is as following:

```
package org.eureka.server;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //ApplicationContext ctx = new SpringApplicationBuilder().bannerMode(Banner.Mode.CONSOLE).run(args);
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And the application.yml is just this:

```
server:
  port: 8761
```

When it is run by `clean spring-boot:run` command, the following exception is raised:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.showBanner(Z)Lorg/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder;
>     at
>   org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:1)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:325)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:296)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>     at
>   org.eureka.server.EurekaServiceApplication.main(EurekaServiceApplication.java:16)
>
> ### ... 6 more [INFO]

When I remove the eureka dependency in pom.xml, the application is run successfully.
Where is wrong?

Comment: Can you ommit the eureka version and add spring cloud using dependency management?

Comment: Please how do i do?

Comment: Must I add the Spring cloud and remove the version of eureka?

Comment: That is how it usually is used, have a look here: http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/ for dalston version for example.

Answer (score 1):

You will change your pom like this

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.roshan</groupId>
    <artifactId>registry</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>registry</name>
    <description></description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Dalston.SR1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>registry</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```